# Call to member function bind_param on non_object

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Ok, before I get started I just want to say that I've read every answer on this site pertaining to this issue, and I still can't get it right. I know PHP is throwing this error because the prepare statement is not returning an object. I just have no idea why. Here's my code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO locations (type, time, street, city, state, country, age, admission, rsvp_limit, keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, description, latitude, longitude, date_posted, member_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(), '1')");
    var_dump($stmt);
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssssssiissssdd", $type, $date, $street, $city, $state, $country, $age, $admission, $rsvp, $keyword1, $keyword2, $keyword3, $description, $latitude, $longitude)) {
      throw new ErrorException($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
    }
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
```

Here's the values being echoed that are sent to this statement:

```
TYPE: Party DATE: 1969-12-31 19:12:00 STREET: 50 Barret Parkway CITY: Marietta STATE: Georgia COUNTRY: United States AGE: 25+ ADMISSION: 20 RSVP: 1000 KEYWORD1: key1test KEYWORD2: key2test KEYWORD3: key3test DESCRIPTION: Description test LATITUDE: 33.950500 LONGITUDE: -84.535900
```

Now keep in mind, the previous string is just an echo string so the all caps words are not actually being sent to the db, just the statements after the colons. I've 20-drupled check the database and all the spellings are correct to the rows in the db all with adequate space and the correct types.

I've been staring at this problem for the past 5 hours while taking breaks to scour the internet for an answer and I draw blanks. Anybody know what's up. If it's any consolation I can add fields in to the database manually by hand and retrieve them with a $_GET variable just fine.

Comment: What does the `var_dump($stmt)` return?

Comment: If the prepare isn't returning an object, what is it returning? Does `$stmt->error` return anything useful?

Comment: Make sure to set `PDO::PARAM_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. That way, in case of an error, a `PDOException` will be thrown.

Comment: time 

is a mysql reserved word
so if you use it as a column name, you should wrap it in backticks (`) though I believe it' one of the reserved words that MySQL is forgiving about

Comment: @Crontab - MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list: 

•
ACTION

 •
BIT

 •
DATE

 •
ENUM

 •
NO

 •
TEXT

 •
TIME

 •
TIMESTAMP - but that's why I deleted this as an answer

Comment: Wouldn't `$stmt` return a boolean value?

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.                   

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php ---- Try `$this->db->bind_param`

Comment: @David [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) is a shortcut method that does return a `mysqli_stmt`

Comment: to @Repox, the var_dump statement returns bool(false);

Comment: @andrewsi, The exact error is "Fatal Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in [then the line number which is where bind_param is]".

Comment: @Truth, I didn't go with PDO this time, all Mysqli, although as a PHP newb I'm not completely sure what exactly the difference is, or even how to set it up.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger - that sounds like your database connection isn't being created properly.

Comment: @andrewsi But how can it not be created properly when I can manually enter in info and use $_GET to get it all out? Thoroughly confused :(

Comment: It's the connection to the database that's not working, not the SQL you're passing to it. Something isn't working when you connect to the database, so when you try to pass your query to it, it generates an error - your query isn't getting to the database in the first place.

Comment: Have a look at the code where you're creating the connection, and check to make sure that the connection is being made, and that there are no errors being generated then.

Comment: @andrewsi that's what i though too, but I'm using literally the same connection that performs the successful $_GET query. On my MAMP installation: function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'localDeals');
    $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
  }

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by a $_GET query? Do you mean that you can access variables by printing them out with $_GET["variable"]?

Comment: @andrewsi. Thanks man, you're last question helped me solve what was wrong! I had forgot this little nugget: $query->close();, so the query connection was not being closed. So this new query could not operate. However, now that that problem is fixed and var_dump($stmt) is returning a positive result array, the data is not being posted to the database at all! It looks like I have a few more hours ahead of me to find out why that's not happening :(

Comment: Glad it helped, and good luck getting the last part finished!

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, feel free to post the answer here, and accept it. It will mark the question as solved for any future visitors having the same problem as yours.